# Display html form with bound data using django

Tags: python, django, html, django-forms

I have django form, but in my HTML i added one extra input field (directly added in html page) which i can access it using request.POST.get('extra_field_name') in my django views.

If form.is_valid() is false i can get the form as HTML with the data displayed in the HTML **but with empty value for the extra added field( directly added in html page)**

How can i get the bounded form data for this newly added extra html field after validation fials.

Please provide your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:

```
html_added_field = ''
error_added_field = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    html_added_field = request.POST.get('extra_field_name')\
    if form.is_valid():
        pass
    else:
        error_added_field = _('Error')

context = {'html_added_field':html_added_field,'error_added_field':error_added_field}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ html_added_field }}" />{% if error_added_field %}<div class="error">{{ error_added_field }}</div>{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article by Bennett may help you.

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/

Briefly, you have to override the `__init__` method of your form, adding there the new "extra_field_name". The fields are included in the self.fields list, so doing:

```
self.fields['extra_field_name'] = forms.CharField(put_here_definitions_for_your_field)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the best way would be for your base django form to handle the extra field. Not using extra fields in the html. However if you can't/don't want, as xbello states, in http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/ you have various tricks for handling dynamic fields.

I found more robust to use the form factory method. A function that generates a dynamic form, prepared for more future changes. Still, you have to decide the best approach :-)